# Not able to view color images using opencv imshow

Tags: python, opencv, ros, realsense

I have trouble viewing color images from R200 realsense camera using the python-opencv interface.
The window is blank when I run this script. 
When I comment out'cv2.namedWindow("Image window", 1)', it shows the first image.

```
import roslib
import sys
import rospy
import cv2
from std_msgs.msg import String
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
#from rospy_tutorials.msg import Floats
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import numpy as np
import math;
import cv2;
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import sys;
#import caffe;
import socket;
#from sklearn import datasets;
import subprocess;

import message_filters
from rospy.numpy_msg import numpy_msg
import time
#####################

import os.path


class image_converter:

# Initializing variables, publishers and subscribers
  def __init__(self):
    print 'show window'
    cv2.namedWindow("Image window", 1)

    self.bridge = CvBridge()

    self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_color", Image, self.callback)


  # The main callback that processes the color and depth data.      
  def callback(self,color):


    start = time.time()
    # acquiring color and depth data (from ROS-python tutorial)
    try:

      frame = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(color, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError, e:
      print e

    frame = np.array(frame, dtype=np.uint8)

    cv2.imshow("Image window", frame)
    print 'test'
    cv2.waitKey(0)


def main(args):
  ic = image_converter()
  rospy.init_node('image_converter', anonymous=True)
  try:
    rospy.spin()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Shutting down"
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of the namedWindow flags value? I see you are using an int there, but in the docs [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#namedwindow) you can find the correct flags, for both C++ and python.

I usually use OpenCV in C++, so i haven't tested, but it should work like this:

```
cv2.namedWindow( "Display window", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
```

You could also define a show function like this one, if it is convenient for your needs:

```
def show(image, name="Image"):
    '''
    Routine to display the image.
    '''
    cv2.namedWindow(name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow(name, image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The function is very trivial, but i didn't code it by myself, so this is the [source](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/67894/cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) of this second code snippet.

Comment: Those macros are usually bound to enum types. If you print cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE it returns 1

Comment: As said, hadn't checked, I was suggesting to check it, thanks for your clarification!

Comment: Ok, I understand, @PriyaNarayanan: only the first frame was showing since you didn't press any key. cv2.waitKey(x) waits x seconds and returns. If a key is pressed before the countdown is elapsed, it returns immediately the value of the pressed key. cv2.waitKey(0) waits indefinitely for a key stroke. That cv2.waitKey(0) in the callback was evidently stopping the ROS main loop you launched with spin(). I hadn't notice you were using ROS.